# MYSQL date formating using group concat

Tags: mysql, group-concat

Sorry for the repost but this is a question I got most of the answer to a month ago. But still haven't got it completely working the way I want.

Have a date field that I am getting out of my DB with the following;

```
SELECT event,event_name,
GROUP_CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(ed.date,'%b %e') ORDER BY ed.date SEPARATOR ',') as date2 
FROM events ev
LEFT JOIN event_dates ed ON ev.eid=ed.eid
WHERE ev.yr='2013' 
GROUP BY ev.eid
```

This produces this list of dates that takes up way to much space.

May 16,May 23,May 30,Jun 6,Jun 20

I want it to look like

May 16,23,30,Jun 6,20

Here is the query I tried based on the input from last time. but it doesn't work because the sub-query doesn't seem to know the event id. guessing i might need to convert it to a join??

```
SELECT DISTINCT ev.event_id, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(race_date,'%a') ORDER BY race_date 
  SEPARATOR ',   ')   as date1,

  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(dm) FROM
  (SELECT CONCAT(
   MONTHNAME(race_date),
   ' ',
   GROUP_CONCAT(DAY(race_date) ORDER BY race_date)
   ) as dm 
FROM event_dates ed1 WHERE ed1.event_id=ev.event_id  
GROUP BY MONTH(race_date))as t) as date2

FROM events ev
JOIN event_dates ed ON ev.event_id = ed.event_id AND ev.race_year = ed.race_year 
GROUP BY event_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you pretty close to what you're looking for:

```
SELECT event_name, date2
FROM (
  SELECT 
    @showMonth:=IF(CONCAT(MONTHNAME(ed.date),ev.eid)=@prevMonth,'',CONCAT(MONTHNAME(ed.date), ' ')),
    event_name,
    MONTHNAME(ed.date), 
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(@showMonth, DATE_FORMAT(ed.date,'%e')) ORDER BY ed.date SEPARATOR ',') as date2,
    @prevMonth:=CONCAT(MONTHNAME(ed.date),ev.eid)
  FROM events ev
    LEFT JOIN event_dates ed ON ev.eid=ed.eid
    JOIN (SELECT @showMonth:='', @prevMonth:='') r
  WHERE ev.yr=2013 
  GROUP BY ev.eid
  ) t
```

[Sample Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a4b4/4)

Comment: This didn't work it suppress the month for the following events that have the same month.

Comment: @davewhirlwind -- just add event to the prevMonth like such: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a4b4/3

Comment: @davewhirlwind -- I've updated the answer to actually use ev.eid instead of event_name -- best of luck!